# How do you keep the sub menu expanded when a sub menu list item is clicked on? use cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, drop-down-menu, menu

I have an expanding menu using jquery. It works well except for one thing: when the user navigates away from the page the menu collapses. I want the menu to stay open when the user clicks on any of the final `< li >` links. All of these links open the same page. Content on these pages is grabbed from a database `http://jsfiddle.net/lekien992/6kkd5fcx/5/`

```
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
Cookie: <span id="display"></span>
</body>
```

Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).

Comment: You can use localStorage for this.

Answer (score 0):

> Content on these pages is grabbed from a database

I assume you are using PHP for your business logic. The problem you described can be solved by determining the 'current' `li` of the page you are on, and then also setting the parent `li` to `.active`. Of course, if your lists are nested not just two times but more, you'll need to bubble up.

This is not a trivial but a complex task, one that can be solved countless ways. Since you tagged javascript and jquery in your question, and judging by your question title, added the `cookies` as a question, I chose a PHP way combined with jQuery. No cookies used in this approach.

---

In this example, I will determine the open list items by:

1. First check which item to open from.
2. Expand parent list elements upwards on client.

**Pros**: easy to implement, infinite nesting.

**Cons**: requires minor client side processing.

In the example below, I will assume that you know the product and page you are currently viewing.

```
<?php
    $current_page = $_GET['page'];
    $current_product = $_GET['product'];
?>

<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul class='menu-root'>
        <li class='<?php if ($current_page == 'home') echo 'active' ?>'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class='<?php if ($current_page == 'products') echo 'active' ?> has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='<?php if ($current_product == 'product_1') echo 'active active-base' ?> has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class='<?php if ($current_product == 'product_1_sub_1') echo 'active active-base' ?>'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
                        <li class='<?php if ($current_product == 'product_1_sub_2') echo 'active active-base' ?> last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class='<?php if ($current_product == 'product_2') echo 'active active-base' ?> has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class='<?php if ($current_product == 'product_2_sub_1') echo 'active active-base' ?>'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
                        <li class='<?php if ($current_product == 'product_2_sub_2') echo 'active active-base' ?> last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='<?php if ($current_page == 'about') echo 'active' ?>'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li class='<?php if ($current_page == 'contact') echo 'active' ?> last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
Cookie: <span id="display"></span>
</body>
```

Then, if you run this script snippet on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cssmenu .menu-root li.active-base').removeClass('active-base').addClass('active').parents('.menu-root .has-sub').addClass('active');
});
```

... then you'll end up with the extra `active-base` class removed, and each `.has-sub` parent will have the class `active`. As you can see, I added `.menu-root` to the root list, so it won't go further up, if you decide to later put this whole thing into another list that should not expand by this logic.

Also, the active-base is not required for the tier 1 items (pages), because they will not make any parent `li` to expand.

Comment: Frist thank you for Answer but i dont know sever because i need it for my homework website basic , I also want to use the next time do not need to change much., i know it use cookies but we just studied this in 2 weeks so need help to complete the only remaining issue in the website. Maybe do not use cookies as well? I have searched google all day today I understand a few things about the cookies but applied to the example above, I can not do it. it should add JQuery